# how to export .xlsx file C# ASP.NET MVC razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel, razor

I would like to export data to a `.xlsx` file, but I can only seem to export to `.xls`.

What's the easiest way to export a `.xlsx` file?

This is the code I use to export to a `.xls` file:

```
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.DataSource = listCatalogue.ToList();
gv.DataBind();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Catalogue.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.Charset = "";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gv.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an external library like [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).

Taken from the [EPPlus documentation](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample):

```
 private void DumpExcel(DataTable tbl)
        {
            using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                //Create the worksheet
                ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Demo");

                //Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the column names on row 1
                ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(tbl, true);

                //Format the header for column 1-3
                using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells["A1:C1"])
                {
                    rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                    rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;                      //Set Pattern for the background to Solid
                    rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(79, 129, 189));  //Set color to dark blue
                    rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.White);
                }

                //Example how to Format Column 1 as numeric 
                using (ExcelRange col = ws.Cells[2, 1, 2 + tbl.Rows.Count, 1])
                {
                    col.Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0.00";
                    col.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Right;
                }

                //Write it back to the client
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=ExcelDemo.xlsx");
                Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: @user3894065 Can you read the documentation of epplus?
Otherwise, the code of nsgocev is well written and understandable#

Comment: @ChristianSauer I added the code after the OP requested more explanations :)