# I am having trouble swapping a file. From XLS to XLSX

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, controller

I'm trying to make a change in the application code, because I've tried it anyway and I'm not having success. I have a reporting tab on my system, but it is only exporting XLS files and I need to switch to XLSX because the XLS is limited to 65,000 lines. I'll show a part of my controler when he's mounting the XLS. I can not show my Service method because it is VERY large and you would be kind of lost.

```
[CustomAuthorize(TipoFuncao.PRINT)]
public ActionResult Index(FiltroRptManifesto filtro)
{
    byte[] result = null;
    bool overflowMonth = false;
    IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    try
    {                
        RptManifestoService rptManifestoService = new RptManifestoService(ModelState);
        result = rptManifestoService.GeraExcel(Server.MapPath("~/Content/RptManifesto.xls"), filtro, ViewBag.Usuario);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             if (ValidateDate(ModelState["DtProtocoloIni"].Value, ModelState["DtProtocoloFin"].Value).Days > 540)
             {
                 overflowMonth = true;
                 throw new Exception();
             };

             Response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie("downloadToken", filtro.DownloadToken));                                    
             return File(result, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "Manifesto.xls");
        }
    }
//...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050765/how-to-export-xlsx-file-c-sharp-asp-net-mvc-razor/25050831 try this answer one. You dont need to struggle lot. Just use EPPlus and create xlsx

Comment: I use NPOI version 2.4. I wanted you to follow the same line of reasoning that I have already done with this NPOI. If it will not change much the logic of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used NPOI so I may be wrong but what happens if you do:

```
var fileName = "Manifesto.xlsx";
return File(result, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName), fileName);
```

or

```
return File(
        result, 
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", 
        "Manifesto.xlsx");
```

Comment: Thank you for your concern to help me, but I still had no positive success. Any other ideas?

Comment: What result are you getting? Is it creating an excel file but the file appears corrupted when you open it,or is it throwing an exception? Are you using `RptManifesto.xls` as a template? That probably needs to be converted to an .xlsx file? Finally, what object are you using to create the excel file? It seems that you need to use `XSSFWorkbook` rather than `HSSFWorkbook`. It's difficult to tell without seeing the code behind `rptManifestoService.GeraExcel` Maybe this link will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21708283/11266990